# VC++ Converting Unicode Traditional Chinese characters to multi byte not always work

Tags: visual-c++, encoding, localization, chinese-locale, multibyte

My application (MFC) is an Unicode app, and I have a third party DLL which only takes the multi-byte characters, so I have to convert the Unicode string to the multi-byte string to pass it to the 3rd party app. Korean, Japanese and even Simplified chinese strings were converted correctly except Traditional chinese. Below describes my attempt. This CPP is encoded in Unicode.

```
    CString strFilePath(_T("中文字 深水埗.docx"));// (_T("中文字 深水埗.docx"));

    wchar_t tcharPath[260];
    wcscpy(tcharPath, (LPCTSTR)(strFilePath));

    CString strAll = strFilePath;
    int strAllLength = strAll.GetLength() + 1;
    int nSize = 0;
    char * pszBuf;
    CPINFO pCPInfo;
    BOOL bUsedDefaultChar = FALSE;
    int nRC = GetCPInfo( CP_ACP, &pCPInfo );
    if ((nSize = WideCharToMultiByte( CP_ACP, 0, strAll, strAllLength, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL )) > 0) 
    {   // Get the size of the buffer length
        pszBuf = (char*)calloc(nSize + 1, sizeof(char));                                      // allocate the buffer
        if (pszBuf == NULL)
            return;              // no more memory
        nRC = WideCharToMultiByte( CP_ACP, 0, strAll, strAll.GetLength(), pszBuf, nSize+1,  NULL, &bUsedDefaultChar );              // store Unicode chars to pszBuf
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        ::MessageBoxA( NULL, pszBuf, "", MB_OK );
        free(pszBuf);            // free it.
    }
```

With Simplified Chinese Windows, the above 6 chinese characters were displayed correctly. Unfortunately, in Traditional Chinese Windows, the 6th character "埗" couldn't be, so it was converted to "?".

Can anyone explain why and tell me if it is possible to convert correctly?